# Convert a timedelta to int

Tags: python

I would like to convert timedelta to int so that I can do math with it but I keep getting this error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncBinaryResolutionError: ufunc 'true_divide' cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('<m8[D]')
```

here is the code:

```
zeit = datetime(2023, 1, 1)
    today = datetime.now()

    new_date = zeit-today

days_int=(new_date / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int)
```

Comment: for total time use `new_date.total_seconds()` and if you want only days in `int` then use `new_date.days`

Comment: `new_date.days` should give you the total number of days if you are after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if u want to convert only days in int then use `new_date.days`